# Extract a substring from end in Bash

Tags: string, bash, shell, ksh

I have a string that looks like this:

`hello/my/name/is/lebowski`

I need to extract the part of the string after the last `/` (`lebowski` in this case). I need to do this is Bash. How do I achieve this? I could do this in Java or Python using regex functionalities, but I don't know how to the same through Bash commands.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Generally, when you have text that looks like a directory path, the `basename` and `dirname` commands can come in handy. `basename` gives you the file's name without the leading path (`lebowski` in this case), and `dirname` gives you the directory name without the file (`hello/my/name/is/` in this case).

Either way, these both spawn a subprocess. You can use variable substitution to get what you want, like so:

```
var="hello/my/name/is/lebowski"
name=${var##*/}
```

I recommend reading the section on substitutions in the `bash` manual for more information.

Answer (score 3):

With simple **`bash`** parameter substitution:

```
s="hello/my/name/is/lebowski"
echo ${s##*/}
lebowski
```

---

> **${var##Pattern}** - Remove from **$var** the longest part of **$Pattern** that matches the *front end* of **$var**

Answer (score 2):

Just like in ksh

```
    st='hello/my/name/is/lebowski'
    echo ${st##*/}

    lebowski
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mystring='hello/my/name/is/lebowski'
$ echo ${mystring##*/}
lebowski
```